# I need to use image to create docker or pull it from AWS ECR to be used in GitHub workflow action container to be the runner of steps on this job

Tags: docker, github, containers, github-actions, amazon-ecr

The error of this code at the create_image job which is failed to pull the image from the first job on this action and the image was created successfully.
I already can push the image to AWS ECR but I don't how to use it in my case,
I tried to create or pull an image in any step on the create_image job but still same error that the image was not pulled or can't pull image.

```
jobs:
   create_image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
      - name: Build docker image
        id: build-image
        run: |
          cd ECR_folder
          docker build -t anguler_image .
          docker images 
          #the image was successfully created in this step.

   create_image:
    needs: create_image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: anguler_image 
      ports:
        - 4200
      volumes:
        - ./:/app/
    
    
    steps:
     - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
```